# How compile Knitr in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: pdftex, r, knitr, texniccenter

some of you have tried using TeXnicCenter to compile Knitr, well I would use TexStudio but it is heavy again.
I appreciate your help

[image: example]

> error
>
> **'Rscript.exe no such file or directory'**

Comment: I don't use that editor but (assuming you have R installed) I would guess the Arguments field should just be the arguments so no`Rscript` at the front, as the full path ending in `Rscript` is already in the Executable field that you show

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

> **Step 1**
>   [image: Step 1]
>
> **Step 2**
>   [image]
>
> **Step 3 --> copi viewer of other options**
>   [image]